# Java redirect exception to file

Tags: bash, redirect

I want to redirect FULL output of my program to a file (including Exceptions) in bash. I can't change content of class. I run it like that:

```
java -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=JLPPolicy -Xmx16M -Xms2M -cp /var/tomcat/bin/ Main > File
```

Exceptions are send to console, which is bad for me. Can I do something with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're using bash you can run the command with `2>&1` appended to the end of the command; e.g

```
> File 2>&1
```

This will redirect file descriptor #2 (stderr) into file descriptor #1 (stdout) which you've already directed to the named file.

You could also try:

```
>& File
```

... which should direct both stdout and stderr.